# Is there another way to restrict SSH user other than chroot jail?

Tags: ssh, debian, jail

I need to create a **safe environment for a foreign SSH** user that has to have very restricted access to our server. That is:

- can only execute commands that are allowed
- can only use specific software that is allowed
- must not be allowed to see/modify/remove folders and files outside of his/her root filesystem under any circumstances

I have tried using chroot jail before using the **jailkit tool** for a smaller project that did not need as much customization and it worked fine, but this project is much bigger and requires a lot more customization in terms of allowed software and commands.

The requirements for the safe environment are:

- the ability to use basic commands such as ls, cd, grep etc.
- the ability to run dotnet scripts
- the ability to utilize running RabbitMQ broker (the broker is running OUTSIDE of the environment)
- the ability to utilize running PostgreSQL database (the database is running OUTSIDE of the environment)

I have heard about **multistrap** or **debootstrap** but I am not sure whether these are adequate tools for solving my problem.

The servers are running on **Debian OS v. 9 and 10**. All the required software is installed in the root filesystem and is running fine. All I need is for the restricted user to be able to utilize it without being able to damage/corrupt the root filesystem.

My questions are:

1. Are there any other useful (better) tools that I have not mentioned that could solve my problem?
2. Are there any useful guides for the software I have mentioned that could solve my problem?

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking questions like this on [unix.se] or [sf].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case somebody is facing the same problem. I solved it using Docker container with separate SSH server and all required software installed on it.